# How to reset hover function after using jquery with css

Tags: jquery, html, css

It's kind of hard to explain, so have a look: http://performasia.com/destinations/.

I'm using an svg map with css hover functions, and I'm trying to have the links at bottom cause the countries to have their hover effect. Also, I'd ideally like it to work vice-versa, so when you hover on the country, it updates the links too (for some reason this isn't working, any ideas?)

The primary problem though, is after you hover over the first china link, it prevents you from seeing the hover effect over the country it lights up again (yes, I know, it's Thailand, not China).

Here's the code I'm using. Each country is a polygon and will have its own id, as well as each li link:

```
 <script>
    $('#list_china').hover(function(){
        $('#map_china').css('fill', 'red');
    ),function(){
        $('#map_china').css('fill', '#86888A');
    });                     
</script>
```

Comment: I see a JS error (look under console)

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 defintions for `map_china` in your svg.

Remove the second one.

And this may be related, you're not closing the tag for:

```
<polyline class="worldMapCountry" fill="#86888A" stroke="#6F7173" stroke-width="0.25" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="186.231,213.648 186.902,214.319
```

Comment: It's still doing it @KingKongFrog

Answer (score 0):

Read what KingKongFrog said and dont forget to bind listeners on document ready.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#list_china').hover(function(){
        $('#map_china').css('fill', 'red');
    ),function(){
        $('#map_china').css('fill', '#86888A');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can I put this in the body or does it need to be in head?

Comment: I use to put all my js code before `</body>` tag. But you can put it wherever you want! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you aren't using css for this.

```
<style>
  #list_china:hover #map_china { background-color: red; }
  #map_china:hover #list_china { background-color: red; }
  #map_china:hover { background-color: red; }
  #list_china:hover { background-color: red; }
</style>
```

If I understand what it is that is being asked in the question, this should work

Comment: Oh...I'm not that great with CSS, but I just have seen that around